# Socket connection in cpanel

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io, cpanel, web-hosting

I have Linux base Cpanel hosting server, And my main web is running in PHP. Also in that server, I serve the `NodeJS` app on port `3000` and host `0.0.0.0` using `PM2`. NodeJs app running fine. but now I want to connect that socket from my PHP app. my PHP app is running on the main domain, ex: mydomain.com. i tried to connect socket using `MY_SERVER_IP:3000` and `mydomain.com:3000` but i not able to connect that socket.

How can i connect NodeJS socket from my PHP app?

Answer (score 0):

I believe one of the reasons that may make your socket app is not running on cPanel that you need to give it a port number between 30000 and 50000 instead of 3000

I struggled in this point till i found this [article](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts)

navigate to the bottom of it then you will notice an orange quoted words that describe what I am talking about here in brief.